# How to match typeof(<some nullable enum) in a dictionary of Types?

Tags: c#, reflection, enums, nullable

I'm using reflection to determine how to format properties on an object.

Here's a dictionary of `formatters`:

```
var formatters = new Dictionary<Type, Func<object, object>>()
{
    { typeof(Enum), x => ((Enum)x)?.FormatEnum() },
    { typeof(DateTime?), x => ((DateTime?)x)?.ToShortDateString() },
    { typeof(string), x => x.ToString().ToLower() }
};
```

Most types will work fine, however when I get the type of my nullable enum `TaskStatus`, the type is not "Enum", it's the name of the type.

I noticed the base type is "Enum", however I don't want to have to check the base type since most other types will work just fine with the type.

For example, checking the type of `string` works fine:

```
typeof(string).FullName = "System.String"
```

But for the `TaskStatus` enum:

```
typeof(Enums.TaskStatus).FullName = "Enums.TaskStatus"
```

So `typeof(Enum) != typeof(Enums.TaskStatus)` which is what is preventing the dictionary from finding a match.

Is there any way to find a match in the `formatters` dictionary without having to put in all the different nullable enum type names I am using?

**Edit:**

Here's my entire code:

```
public class NoteHistory
{
    [JsonProperty("Status")]
    public TaskStatus? TaskStatus { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("CreatedDate")]
    public DateTime? CreatedDate { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("Description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; } // not interested in comparing this
}

public enum TaskStatus
{
    ToDo,
    Done
}

public static void DisplayValues()
{
    var noteHistory1 = new NoteHistory
    {
        TaskStatus = TaskStatus.ToDo
    };

    var noteHistory2 = new NoteHistory
    {
        TaskStatus = TaskStatus.Done
    };

    // Get all properties with JsonProperty attr.
    var propertiesToCompare = typeof(NoteHistory)
        .GetProperties()
        .Where(x => x.CustomAttributes
            .Any(y => y.AttributeType.Name == nameof(JsonPropertyAttribute)));

    var comparers = new Dictionary<Type, Func<object, object, bool>>
    {
        { typeof(string), (x, y) => !string.Equals(x?.ToString(), y?.ToString(), StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) }
    };

    var formatters = new Dictionary<Type, Func<object, object>>()
    {
        { typeof(Enum), x => ((Enum)x)?.FormatEnum() }, // doesn't work
        { typeof(DateTime?), x => ((DateTime?)x)?.ToShortDateString() },
        { typeof(string), x => x.ToString().ToLower() },
    };

    foreach (var propertyToCompare in propertiesToCompare)
    {
        var prop1Value = propertyToCompare.GetValue(noteHistory1);
        var prop2Value = propertyToCompare.GetValue(noteHistory2);

        Func<object, object, bool> comparer;
        comparers.TryGetValue(propertyToCompare.PropertyType, out comparer);

        var hasChanged = comparer?.Invoke(prop1Value, prop2Value) ?? prop1Value != prop2Value;

        if (hasChanged)
        {
            Func<object, object> formatter;
            formatters.TryGetValue(propertyToCompare.PropertyType, out formatter);

            var formattedValue = formatter?.Invoke(noteHistory2);
            // TODO: display the value
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: _"I'm using reflection to determine how to format properties on an object."_ - May I ask why?

Comment: I'm comparing objects and I need to detect any changes between the properties. I need to display each change, so instead of writing a new `if` statement each time a new property is added, and in that `if` statement having the formatting logic, I'd rather add attributes to the properties and use reflection to detect the changes and format the display values.

Comment: You need to show the code where you use this, otherwise we can't give you a solution.

Comment: @PoulBak I've updated the question.

Comment: All enums are distinct types that inherit from `Enum`. You can check if a type is an enum type with the `IsEnum` property.

Comment: if the issue is type name equality, try this: ``typeof(Enums.TaskStatus).BaseType.FullName`` which is equal to ``typeof(Enum)``

Comment: A Dictionary with `Type` keys is a bad idea, since (as you have seen) a dictionary matches keys exact while you want `is` functionality.

Comment: You have used reflection, do you still care about the efficiency? Just extra check the BaseType.

Comment: "I noticed the base type is "Enum", however I don't want to have to check the base type since most other types will work just fine with the type." no they won't. Any derived class won't work unless you use `BaseType`. Also you should use `Nullable.GetUnderlyingType` to get the `T` type of a Nullable<T>`

Comment: @Charlieface the properties are all built-in types.

Comment: So why can't you use the `BaseType` property, or add all possible enums?

Comment: @Charlieface because there are too many enums, and if more enums get added, I'll need to add them to the dict, which defeats the purpose. BaseType property doesn't work because for example `int` and `DateTime` both have `ValueType` as their base type.

Comment: So check the type itself as well as the base type, and either way you will get a match.